# Plugin Profiler produces an error on CRM while it successfully executes when on Debugger

Tags: debugging, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, registration, profiler

I'm using the steps here to debug my plugin: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778280

1- I ran my plugin on CRM

2- I got an error log and I downloaded it
[image]

3- I Debugged the log from the Registration tool Debugger using Visual Studio and it executed successfully without any errors.

[image]

How come the CRM produced an error while the debug using the downloaded log executed successfully ?

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots

Comment: Does this Error Log indicate the existence of an error or is this a file that is generated by the profiler whether an error exists or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin profiler has a couple options for how it creates the data required to debug locally.  The default option, is to raise an exception that creates the plugin context, this is the error you're seeing.